# Lazarus 2.2.0 cannot create file on disk?

Tags: lazarus

The code below shows: "Unable to create file "test.txt". Access is denied."

```
var F: TFileStream;
begin
  F := TFileStream.Create('test.txt', fmCreate);
  F.free;
end;
```

Am I doing something wrong? Folder is not protected in any way and all other programs can write files there. Lazarus 2.2.0 on Windows 7.

Comment: How do you know without an explicit path to the file?  Try adding a full path to the file name.

Comment: @MartynA It should create a file in the same dir as the exe. Also I tried full path and no change.

Comment: As I don't have the same version, neither of Lazarus nor Windows, I can only say that for me it works perfectly well with a path like `c:\tmp\text.txt`. Your path is probably different, maybe one where your program is not allowed to write, since you got an "Access denied" error.

Comment: @TomBrunberg It seems there is a bug in Lazarus 2.2.0 for Windows.

Comment: Ok, if you say so.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't guaranteed create the file in the same dir as the EXE. It creates the file in the working dir of the application, which is not necessarily the EXE dir, which varies depending on how you execute the EXE.

Try

```
 var sExePath : string;
 .. 
 sExePath := includetrailingpathdelimiter(ExtractFilePath(paramstr(0)));
  F := TFileStream.Create(sExePath+'test.txt', fmCreate);
```

Note this is similar to Delphi